# ERROR RESHAPE the number of elements must not change

Tags: matlab, reshape

the following code has me  the error message "To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change"

```
for i=1:11
s=num2str(i);
filename=['D:\test matlab\',s,'.tif'];
Image=imread(filename);
r=size(Image,1);
c=size(Image,2);
numberarray=r*c;
data=reshape(Image,1,numberarray);
```

The last line produces the error `%Error using reshape .
produced_data(i,1:numberarray)=data;`

Image=333x300x11 single

numberarray=99900

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Assuming the intent of your loop is to slice along the third dimension of `Image` you need to actually index into `Image` in your `size` and `reshape` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your image likely is in color; hence the 3rd dimension might be > 1.
`colorinformation=size(Image,3); % Red, Green, Blue`

solution is then to:

- convert image to grayscale

`Image = rgb2gray(Image)`

- use the 3 color dimensions in the reshape as well.

`data=reshape(Image,1,numberarray,size(Image,3));`